# Octave/matlab: uint8 array to float

Tags: matlab, floating-point, octave, endianness

I'm receiving Big-endian data from a socket (using the socket package) in Octave.

Some parts of this data contain float (32bit) values, but these are encoded as uint8's.

For example: (67  128    0    0)

Is there a way in Octave to calculate the corresponding float/single value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do it is using [`typecast()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/typecast.html):

```
octave> typecast (uint8 ([67 128 0 0]), "single")
ans =    4.6012e-41
```

If you have an endianess issue, use [`swapbytes()`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/swapbytes.html):

```
octave> swapbytes (typecast (uint8 ([67 128 0 0]), "single"))
ans =  256
```

If you want to play more with it, or require more flexibility, take also a look at [`bitpack()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/bitpack.html) and [`bitunpack()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/bitunpack.html):

```
octave> data = uint8 ([67  128    0    0   67  127    0    0   67  126    0    0   67  125    0    0])
data =

   67  128    0    0   67  127    0    0   67  126    0    0   67  125    0    0

octave> bitpack (bitunpack (flipud (reshape (data, 4, []))), "single")
ans =

   256
   255
   254
   253
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Tnx